# 'Medicine' object has no attribute 'add' error

Tags: python, django

I want to add medicine to my cart from a medicine list. I created a view but when I click add button it gives this error:

> AttributeError at /cart/3/ 'Medicine' object has no attribute 'add'

I want that when a user click `+` button, medicine will be added to the users cart. I can add it from admin panel but cannot add from web page. Here are my codes. Please help me.

**carts/views.py**

```
def update_cart(request, id):
    current_user = request.user
    cart = Cart.objects.filter().first()

    try:
        medicine = Medicine.objects.get(id=id)
    except Medicine.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    cart.product.add(medicine)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/cart")
```

**carts/models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.TextField(User)
    product = models.OneToOneField(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**plus button in html **

```
<a href="/cart/{{medicine.id}}" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-success">
              <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i><br/>
            </a>
```

Comment: You have not defined a method 'add' for your 'Cart' class. Without this, it doesn't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cart to Product have [`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) relation. So `add` will not work here. You need to update the code like this:

```
cart.product = medicine
cart.save()
```

Or you can make it [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) relation. For example:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    # rest of the code
    product = models.ManyToMany(Medicine)
    # rest of the code
```